# How to handle special character in filter in SolrNet?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I'm working on SolrNet 3.6 which is used in e-Commerce site based on ASP.NET MVC3 with C#.

There is one filter called "cpu socket type" and its values are

1. AM2+
2. AM3+
3. AM2

Solr is working properly when you filter with "AM2" but it is not working when you filter with "AM2+" or "AM3+". At same time we can not get any result or an error also. I know that this issue is related with special character but don't know how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [SolrNet Wiki Page on Querying](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Querying), try using the `SolrQueryByField` method as:

> It also has the benefit that it handles special character escaping for you.

So your code would look similar to this, assuming your field was named `cpusockettype` in your solr schema.xml file.

```
ISolrOperations<Item> solr = ...
var items = solr.Query(new SolrQueryByField("cpusockettype", "AM2+"));
```